# How to setTimeout for listening to messages coming from window.postMessage?

Tags: javascript, postmessage

How can I listen to the messages coming from `window.postMessage` only for amount of time?

I tried to use `setTimeout` inside the the event listener's function but this doesn't work.

**My try:**

```
function processMessages(message) {
//setTimeout(function() {
    if (message) {
        console.log("you have a message");
    } else {
        console.log("no messages came"); //<=== I can't get here!
    }
//},10000);
    window.removeEventListener("message", processMessages, false);
}

window.addEventListener("message", processMessages, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange your code to place `.removeEventListener()` call within `setTimeout()`, which does not need to be within `processMessage` function

```
function processMessages(message) {
    if (message) {
        console.log("you have a message");
    } else {
        console.log("no messages came"); //<=== I can't get here!
    }   
}

window.addEventListener("message", processMessages, false);

var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                window.removeEventListener("message", processMessages, false);
              }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You setTimeout the event run, but your removeEventListener of message doesn;t delay.